# what is best way to monitor IIS 6.0?

Tags: iis-6

monitoring can be include source ip, what is being served by iis, which work processor is being used, how much current load on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Performance counters will tell you about IIS load.  Run perfmon.exe to see them.

And IIS produces logs that are by default under C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1 showing every single file served, including requester's IP address and more.